# Click on Anchor tag automatically via C# Code(Windows desktop application)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, winforms

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="F23" id="viewtag">Click</a>
```

I have this link in my page , i need to click automatically when i traverse the doc,

After click it show some information the Div, I want to Fetch that information..
So i need this.. Anyone can help me ...

Comment: http://watin.org/
Whith that DLLs you can simulate click and read div content

Comment: didnt get the answer or hint

Comment: WatiN.Core.dll
Interop.SHDocVw.dll
about that DLLs you can read in watin.org

Comment: @NarekArzumanyan where i can find these dll sir

Comment: If this is a *local* (WinForms) application how are you showing HTML content? And what does it have to do with ASP.NET?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
using (var browser = new IE("Your URI)")
{
    browser.Link(linkId).Click();
    var div = browser.Div(divId);
}
```

Comment: can you please provide me the way to find the dll

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/watin/files/WatiN%202.x/2.1/
then click on WatiN-2.1.0.1196.zip